Creating a fixed image(doesn't scroll) on an individual page
On Cargo Collective, I want to create a fixed gif, almost like a header on an individuals page. The intention is to have this gif continuously playing on the top and all the images/words below it to scroll under the gif. This is only for ONE unique page. I already have a header and nav bar on the left. What I am hoping is to import a GIF, place it in place, and then keep it static/fixed at the top, but I haven't found a way to do that.
I tried to add the image and look up fixed images. But I keep getting backgrounds, which this isn't. I want the stuff to scroll under this gif, not over it. I tried to look it up several times but have had no luck in figuring out how to incorporate the fixed code I'm looking for.

Normally you would use position:fixed in CSS. Can you add the code that you tried?

{image 9 scale="25"}
I tried it with position:fixed as well. Same result, as in nothing is happening. I am not good at this stuff but figured this wouldn't be too hard.

To fix a div you need <div style="position:fixed"><img src=""></div>. But if that doesn't work for you, you'll need to post your complete code in your question. Otherwise we cannot reproduce your issue.
